# Downloaded PDF in R - Corrupted File

Tags: r, pdf, corrupt-data

I've been trying to download some pdfs in R, with the following code:

```
link <- paste0("http://","www.energisa.com.br/empresa/paginas/servicos-online/autoatendimento/extrato-segunda-via-publica-visualizacao.aspx?ano=2017&mes=9&cdc=6/681274-7&fatura=55152")

data_referencia <- seq(as.Date("2017-10-01"), length = 1, by = "-1 month")    
download.file(link, destfile = paste0("energisa_", data_referencia,".pdf"), mode = "wb")
```

Everything goes fine until I open the pdf file (error message pops-up):

[image]

I tried to change the "`download.file()`" parameter, but the problem persisted.

Can you help me out?

Comment: `object 'k' not found`

Comment: Sorry @PoGibas, I changed the code to simplify...

Comment: If i try to go to that URL in a new browser session I don't see a PDF; I see some sort of page asking me to choose a city. Seems like you might need to log in or something. There is server side code that's preventing the direct download of the file. Most likely the file you are downloading in the HTML for that welcome page and not the PDF you want.

Comment: @MrFlick, you can choose any city as a reference to open the pdf. Or if you enter [link](http://www.energisa.com.br/empresa/Paginas/servicos-online/autoatendimento/extrato-e-2via-da-conta.aspx) and type "6/681274-7" on "Unidade Consumidora" field (in the bottom of the page), you'll see the last 12 files published, and the first one has the pdf link.

Comment: The weird fact is that R seems to save only a partition of the pdf because all saved files have the same size (roughly 33Kb).

Comment: You see, R can't "click" on a city or type in a date. `download.file()` can only download files. I you need to do a complicated interaction with a website, perhaps you should look into using [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RSelenium). IIt's not downloading the PDF at all (you are just saving it with a PDF extension). I bet if you look at what's downloaded with a text editor you'll see the HTML code for that welcome page).

Comment: But once you select the city, if you copy the link and put it in another browser it goes fine. But the weird thing is that R actually downloads something, but it is corrupted.

Comment: R downloads something: yes. It is corrupted: naja. R downloaded the file located at your URL, which is an HTML file, and not a PDF file. If you try to open an HTML file with your PDF-reader, it will tell you 'file is corrupted', but it's actually just a non-PDF file that the PDF-reader can't read

Comment: @KenS. Makes sense. I will try to use RSelenium as MrFlick suggested, though.